# How to create pair of keys of Map

Tags: scala

For exemple:

```
mylist: Map("Start" -> 2015-05-30T00:00:00.000Z, "Daily" -> 2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z, "Hourly" -> 2015-06-03T08:00:00.000Z, "End" -> 2015-06-04T15:00:00.000Z)
```

I want to output as following format:

```
myout: List( ("Start" -> 2015-05-30T00:00:00.000Z, "Daily" -> 2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z), ("Daily" -> 2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z, "Hourly" -> 2015-06-03T08:00:00.000Z), ("Hourly" -> 2015-06-03T08:00:00.000Z, "End" -> 2015-06-04T15:00:00.000) )
OR
myout: List( ("Start", "Daily"), ("Daily", "Hourly"), ("Hourly", "End"))
```

Case 1: Always start with "Start" key, Anything comes before "Start" key ignore it. Same for last "End" key

```
 mylist: Map(Hourly -> 2015-06-01T08:00:00.000Z, Start -> 2015-05-30T00:00:00.000Z, Daily -> 2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z,  End -> 2015-06-04T15:00:00.000Z, Weekly-> 2015-06-05T00:00:00.000Z)
```

output should like:

```
  List((Start, Daily), (Daily, End))
```

I am looking output using scala.

Comment: Is it based on the order of the original ``Map``? ``Map`` is not supposed to be oredered

Comment: What you want cannot be done using map. A map simply applies the given to all the elements, it cannot access previous members. What you need is a for loop (or for comprehension).

Answer (score 1):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

val x = ListMap("Start" -> "x", "Daily" -> "y", "Hourly" -> "z", "End" -> "a")

x.toList.sliding(2).map( a => (a(0)._1, a(1)._1)).toList

List((Start,Daily), (Daily,Hourly), (Hourly,End))
```

Comment: If you can live with `Set()`s, instead of tuples, it can be shortened to: `x.keys.sliding(2).toList`

Answer (score 0):

Since a `Map` is not ordered, I have modified the input data to get stable results.

As for the 1st question

```
val m = 
  Map(
    "1-Start" -> "2015-05-30T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "2-Daily" -> "2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "3-Hourly" -> "2015-06-03T08:00:00.000Z", 
    "4-End" -> "2015-06-04T15:00:00.000Z")
```

The basic idea is to `zip` the list of keys with its own tail to get the pairs:

```
scala> m.keys.toList.sorted.zip(m.keys.toList.sorted.tail)
res57: List[(String, String)] = List((1-Start,2-Daily), (2-Daily,3-Hourly), 
  (3-Hourly,4-End))
```

To simplify the expression a "pipe forward operator" is helpful:

```
object PipeForwardContainer {
  implicit class PipeForward[T](val v: T) extends AnyVal {
    def |>[R](f: T => R): R = {
      f(v)
    }
  }
}

import PipeForwardContainer._
```

This operator provides a reference to the intermediate result. Therefore you can write:

```
scala> m.keys.toList.sorted |> { l => l.zip(l.tail) }
res97: List[(String, String)] = List((1-Start,2-Daily), (2-Daily,3-Hourly), 
  (3-Hourly,4-End))
```

---

As for the 2nd question

```
val m = 
  Map(
    "1-Hourly" -> "2015-06-03T08:00:00.000Z", 
    "2-Start" -> "2015-05-30T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "3-Daily" -> "2015-06-02T00:00:00.000Z", 
    "4-End" -> "2015-06-04T15:00:00.000Z",
    "5-Weekly"-> "2015-06-05T00:00:00.000Z")
```

To get the raw list you can `slice` out the relevant elements by index:

```
scala> m.keys.toList.sorted |> { l => 
  l.slice(l.indexOf("2-Start"), l.indexOf("4-End") + 1) }
res96: List[String] = List(2-Start, 3-Daily, 4-End)
```

Again with `zip` to get the pairs:

```
scala> m.keys.toList.sorted |> { l => 
    l.slice(l.indexOf("2-Start"), l.indexOf("4-End") + 1) 
  } |> { l => l.zip(l.tail) }
res98: List[(String, String)] = List((1-Start,2-Daily), (2-Daily,3-Hourly), 
  (3-Hourly,4-End))
```